# how struct work are queued in workqueue if already older instance of work is pending

Tags: linux-kernel, interrupt-handling

It is mentioned in "Understanding the linux kernel" that If a work is queued in workqueue and pending, the pending status of work will be set so the new instance of work can't be queued.

So does it mean that until the pending work not served; no future work objects will be queued?

Answer (score 0):

The work item itself cannot be queued multiple times; other work items still can be queued.